# How to filter by variable being in list of values?

Tags: python, sparql, rdf

I have this SPARQL query:

```
all_actors = rdf.query(
    """ SELECT DISTINCT ?actor
        WHERE {
            ?movie pred:hasActor ?actor . 
        } 
        GROUP BY ?actor 
        HAVING (COUNT(?movie) >= """ + str(LEAST_MOVIES) + ')',
initNs={'pred': ns_predicates})
```

and I also have a pandas series (or a python list) of movies called `unique_movies`. Both `?movie` and the series have string values of IMDb IDs for movies.

I want to filter the results in the first query by enforcing that `?movie` should be in `unique_movies`.

How do I do that? Do I need to somehow write all the movies in `unique_movies` in text (they are about ~200) and perform string concatenation? I can't find any similar example.

Edit:

I tried this:

```
our_movies = ' '.join(unique_movies.index)
all_actors = rdf.query(
    """ SELECT DISTINCT ?actor
        WHERE {
            ?movie pred:hasActor ?actor .
            VALUES ?movie { """ + our_movies + """ }
        } 
        GROUP BY ?actor 
        HAVING (COUNT(?movie) >= """ + str(LEAST_MOVIES) + ')',
    initNs={'pred': ns_predicates})
```

where our_movies is a string like "imdb_id1 imdb_id2 ... imdb_idN" but I am getting a `pyparsing.ParseException: Expected {SelectQuery | ConstructQuery | DescribeQuery | AskQuery}, found 'V'  (at char 106), (line:4, col:17)`

Comment: just put it into a SPARQL 1.1 `VALUES` clause in your query string

Comment: How? String concatenation?

Comment: yes, you can also pass the list of movie IDs via string interpolation, not the separator must be whitespace, i.e. in the end it should be `SELECT ... WHERE { VALUES ?movie { <movie_uri_1>  <movie_uri_2> ... <movie_uri_n>}  ... }`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I editted my answer. What am I doing wrong? (I am not really into SPARQL I just want to make my dataset)

Comment: can you show the generated string please by using `print` in Python? Also, as you can see from my comment, the URIs are put into angle brackets. You didn't do this. Or how do the entries of your list look like?